# GWT client communicates with public server

Tags: gwt, web-applications, httprequest

I am creating this client webapp without server side. For example, I want this client to simply make HTTP request with public websites, like http://www.google.com. So far I have used RequestBuilder to build my HTTP requests, but when I run the app in dev mode, the response code for my request is always 0. And after I built it and made request on hmtl file, it gave the same result. It looks to me that the client is not communicating with the public internet but only local server (which is empty).

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));
```

Is there anyway that I can make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make XHR requests to a different server from where you download your page, unless you enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in the server.

google.com has not enabled CORS, so you cannot request their pages usin XHR.

If you own the domain you want to request enable CORS, [here](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29) you have a filter example for a java backend.

If you simply want to display a 3party web in your ui you can insert it as an iframe, but be aware that you cannot read the iframe content because it is in a different domain.

Note that CORS works in almost browsers, but for IE/8-9 you have to use `XDomainRequest`

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction. Basically, it's impossible to make requests to a different domain directly. If you just want to display that website as is, you can use an iframe to do it; if you want to make more specific requests, then you will need to use something like [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to do it, but that requires that the server actually support it.

Comment: @Marconious this sentence is not enterely true `it's impossible to make requests to a different domain directly`. Actually most browsers nowadays supports the CORS mechanism, so as you can send ajax request to any domain if this domain sends back certain headers. IE8-IE9 instead of CORS have XDomainRequest though.